# Visual Studio 2015 system requirements

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2015, system-requirements

What are Visual Studio 2015 system requirements regarding Internet Explorer (IE)?

The [respective Microsoft page](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx) states that Visual Studio 2013 needs IE 10, yet nothing is mentioned for the 2015 release.

Comment: When I installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with only Internet Explorer 8 installed the installer gave pretty much same warning as given in the requirements for 2013: "This version of Visual Studio works best with Internet Explorer 10 or higher. If Internet Explorer 10 is not installed on your computer, some features might not work as expected.". The only feature I've noticed not working as expected is signing into to Visual Studio. This may or may not be a coincidence. Signing in with 2013 works for me with IE 8 installed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. For me Diagnostic Tools aren't working properly with Internet Explorer 9 for the following reason: "The content requires a new version of Internet Explorer". Visual Studio offered me to install IE 11, yet it's not an option for me atm. Could someone confirm that Diagnostic Tools are fully functional with Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: I can only conforming that it doesn't work for me with IE 8 as well, though it just says that it couldn't load DiagnosticsHubPackage. If that's your real question you should update your question to actually ask that.

Comment: I mentioned Diagnostic Tools since that's the only unavailable feature I discovered in Visual Studio 2015 until now while running IE9. Ideally I would work towards getting "the right" IE version installed (what requires an effort when you don't manage your machine) to avoid further surprises.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 is fully functional with IE11 (as expected). Whether IE10 is sufficient is still an open question for me.